# How to read multipart response with RESTful API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I'm calling one restful api and the response content-type of the api is image/png, text/plain,text/xml etc based on the file uploaded originally into file repository.

I have tired with below code..

```
HttpEntity<?> wsRequest =
          new HttpEntity<>(
              request,
              this.createHttpHeader(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
      MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
      converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
      messageConverters.add(converter);
      restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

      ResponseEntity<Object> wsResponse =
          restTemplate.exchange(
              url,
              HttpMethod.POST,
              wsRequest,
              new ParameterizedTypeReference<Object>() {});
```

Able to read the text/plain type response but remaining formats getting issue.

Error Info

```
- RestClientException for request=
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [image/png]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 137)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 137)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

how api returning the response? added screenshots for the reference.

[image]

[image]